# how to add email notifications when developers push code to gitHub

Tags: git, github, github-services

I need to add at least 10 people to my github on a project we are working on so they can get email notifications.  The issue is instructions per my screenshot say its only going to take 2 email addresses ? how can they all get updates when a party pushes code ?

[image]

does each person need to update their config file like this locally:

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try watching the repository instead
https://help.github.com/articles/watching-repositories/

All watchers will get notifications when someone opens a PR against any of the branches in the repository.

Else set up Google Group and ask all to register and sign up for that Google group. Make sure the group is private.

Comment: Is this only for PR ? My team we all share the same fork.  So there is onl one repo.  I just want that they call can get a email from github when someone 'pushes' code.